# Failed to update database with SqlCommand and also with DB Entity in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, savechanges

I have made a program with a simple SQL Server `.mdf` database file.

First: I have connected to the database using `SqlConnection` and tried to insert some data using `SqlCommand`. The `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of affected rows successfully for example 1 or 2 ... etc.

But when I use Server Explorer to view the data of the table, there is nothing inserted!?

Then I have used model entity object and DataSource. On `SaveChanges` function I get also the number of affected rows successfully, but there is no data inserted in Table on viewing it.

When I make a query using Server Explorer, the data will be inserted successfully and I can view it!!? Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the **connection string** you're using in your C# app?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use `AttachDbFilename`

Answer (score 0):

thank you marc_s, you gave me a hint "ConnectionString". As I created a database mdf with server explorer, I realized now, there is two mdf files created. One is located in base folder of project and the other located in bin/debug folder. I don't why there is two of them, howerver it solved my problem. Thanks